# Cual es la manera correcta de indicar la url al hacer fetch javascrip?

Tags: javascript, fetch, asp.net-core-mvc

Estoy trabajando con .net core mvc y javascript. Me encuentro con el siguiente problema, el cual mi controlador HttpPost recibe dos parametros (int id y WorkOrder w) ahora bien, se debe poder cargar imagenes (la clase WorkOrder cuenta con una propiedad IFormFileCollection) y el controlador tiene la logica necesaria para guardar esas imagenes. El problema es que al hacer fetch con javascript e ingresar la url ('/WorkOrder/Create') recibo el error 404. Intenté crear otro endpoint (Prueba) sin parametros y al ejecutar en el fetch con url '/WorkOrder/Prueba' si se ejecuta esa linea en mi controlador de prueba.
Ahora bien, me gustaria saber de qué manera debo escribir la url en el fetch para que se ejecute mi controlador con parametros( los cuales son int id, WorkOrder w).

Esto es algo de mi controlador:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? id, WorkOrder w)
{
     //Images
        w.Images = Request.Form.Files;
        string uniqueImageName = null;
        string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webhostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images");
        if (w.Images != null && w.Images.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (IFormFile image in w.Images)
            {                 
                uniqueImageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "-" + image.FileName;
                string filePathImage = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueImageName);
                image.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePathImage, FileMode.Create));
            }
        }
       return Json(new { result = true});
}
```

Esto es algo de lo que se hizo con javascript:

```
var formData = new FormData();
file.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++) {
        var thumbnail_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30000) + '_' + Date.now();
        createThumbnail(file, i, thumbnail_id);
        formData.append(thumbnail_id, file.files[i])
    }
    e.target.value = '';
});

publish.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('/WorkOrder/Create',{
        method: 'POST',           
        body: formData
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        clearFormDataAndThumbnails();
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿Has probado realizar la misma petición desde Postman o algún software/servicio parecido? Podrías realizar esto y descartar el error del lado del cliente que a simple vista parece estar bien implementado.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la implementación del método *createThumbnail* para identificar como se agregan las imágenes al formData?

Comment: Pude hacer que funcionara, solamente quite "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]" de mi controlador y ahora si que puedo hacer debug en el controlador, el problema ahora es que el objeto de la clase WorkOrder w llega vacio, al momento de clickear submit los datos del formulario no se envian al controlador y mucho menos los recibe el objeto "w", es mas, tambien el id llega vacio. Sabes algo al respecto ?